# Is Bootstrap usable in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Can I edit all text fields (tr's) with Bootstrap's modal? including the new fields that I can create. Some friend told me that is usable in this case, but I haven't worked with this framework before. I've made some research, and tried some codes posted here and on the internet, but haven't worked. If this is not difficult to do and you guys can help me I'll appreciate it. I'm trying to make mini projects for self learning, and obviously after starting with big ones in school.

**Code:**
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="mainTable" name="mainTable" align="center" border="0" width="auto">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="number" id="regsAmount" name="regsAmount" style="width:40px; text-align: center;">
            <input type="button" id="submitAmount" name="submitAmount" style="width:auto;" value="Add">
            <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:120px; border-width:2px;">Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:120px; border-width:2px;">Last Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:120px; border-width:2px;">ID</th>
            <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:250px; border-width:2px;">Mail</th>
            <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:120px; border-width:2px;">Username</th>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">
          <td>

          </td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td><button type="button" data-id="1" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">
          <td></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td><button type="button" data-id="2" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">
          <td></td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td><button type="button" data-id="3" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">
          <td></td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td><button type="button" data-id="4" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">
          <td></td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td><button type="button" data-id="5" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p align="center"><input type="button" id="saveRegs" name="saveRegs" value="Save All" style="width:auto;" onclick="disable_inp()"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
function disable_inp()
{
  $("tr:gt(0) td:has(input)").text(function() 
  {
    return $('input', this).val();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{  
    $(document).on('click', "#submitAmount", function()
    {
      var ValReg = $("#regsAmount").val();
      var i = 1;
      var array = new Array(5)
      array = ["<input type='text' class='reqField'>", "<input type='text' class='reqField'>", "<input type='text'  class='reqField'>", "<input type='text' class='reqField'>", "<input type='text' class='reqField'>"];

      while (i <= ValReg) 
      {
        $("#mainTable").last().append("<tr></tr>");
        $("tr").last().append('<td> </td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[0] + '</td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[1] + '</td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[2] + '</td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[3] + '</td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[4] + '</td>');
        i++;
      }
})
});
```

Comment: What didn't work? Do you have errors in console? If you haven't checked then that should be your first place to start. Then you need to learn about debugging by setting break points and inspecting variables.

Comment: Examples like [this one](http://formvalidation.io/examples/loading-saving-data-modal/) haven't worked for me. And that's the big thing, i'm kinda noob @ frameworks use.

Comment: But you need to define what "doesn't work" means. Is the modal showing, is the submit event occurring, are you having issues selecting the element to append to, are you selecting the proper element but it doesn't append anything, are there runtime errors that are preventing anything from running? These are basic debugging steps you need to take before posting a question. Shoving your work at someone and saying "I'm a noob, it doesn't work fix it" doesn't help you become a better developer. I could care less your level of experience if you present a proper question.

Comment: Sorry, modal doesn't show, that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/bootbox/4.2.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    function disable_inp()
    {
      $("tr:gt(0) td:has(input)").text(function() 
      {
        return $('input', this).val();
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {  
        $(document).on('click', "#submitAmount", function()
        {

          var ValReg = $("#regsAmount").val();
          var i = 1;
          var array = new Array(5)
          array = ["<input type='text' class='reqField'>", "<input type='text' class='reqField'>", "<input type='text'  class='reqField'>", "<input type='text' class='reqField'>", "<input type='text' class='reqField'>"];

          while (i <= ValReg) 
          {
            $("#mainTable").last().append("<tr></tr>");
            $("tr").last().append('<td> </td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[0] + '</td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[1] + '</td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[2] + '</td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[3] + '</td>' + '<td align="center">' + array[4] + '</td>');
            i++;
          }live
    })

    $('.editButton').on('click', function() {
            // Get the record's ID via attribute
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');


                // Populate the form fields with the data returned from server


                // Show the dialog
                bootbox
                    .dialog({
                        title: 'Edit the user profile',
                        message: $('#userForm'),
                        show: false // We will show it manually later
                    })
                    .on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                        $('#userForm')
                            .show()                             // Show the login form

                    })
                    .on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                        // Bootbox will remove the modal (including the body which contains the login form)
                        // after hiding the modal
                        // Therefor, we need to backup the form
                        $('#userForm').hide().appendTo('body');
                    })
                    .modal('show');

        });



    $('table tbody tr  td').on('click',function(){

            $("#name").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);

        $("#lastname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[2].textContent);


        $("#id").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[3].textContent);

        $("#mail").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[4].textContent);

        $("#username").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[5].textContent);

    });
 }); 
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="mainTable" name="mainTable" align="center" border="0" width="auto">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <input type="number" id="regsAmount" name="regsAmount" style="width:40px; text-align: center;">
                <input type="button" id="submitAmount" name="submitAmount" style="width:auto;" value="Add">
                <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:120px; border-width:2px;">Name</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:120px; border-width:2px;">Last Name</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:120px; border-width:2px;">ID</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:250px; border-width:2px;">Mail</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; border-style:solid; width:120px; border-width:2px;">Username</th>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
              <td>

              </td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td><button type="button" data-id="1" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
              <td></td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>8</td>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td><button type="button" data-id="2" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
              <td></td>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>15</td>
              <td><button type="button" data-id="3" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
              <td></td>
              <td>16</td>
              <td>17</td>
              <td>18</td>
              <td>19</td>
              <td>20</td>
              <td><button type="button" data-id="4" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
              <td></td>
              <td>21</td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>23</td>
              <td>24</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td><button type="button" data-id="5" class="btn btn-default editButton">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <p align="center"><input type="button" id="saveRegs" name="saveRegs" value="Save All" style="width:auto;" onclick="disable_inp()"></p>

    <form id="userForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='name' name="name" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Last name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text"  id='lastname' class="form-control" name="lastname" />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">id</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='id' name="id" />
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Mail</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='mail' name="mail" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">username</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" id='username' class="form-control" name="username" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @xblade52 i have updated my answer On click on edit button it display model .

Comment: Oh, it worked. The data didn't load in form but you helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: we can do that as well @xblade52 i will update my answer.

Comment: And will do the modifying process into the tr's? If you do that will be awesome. I'll try to get into a course because this framework is interesting.

Comment: Hey @xblade52 please check i have upadate my answer ? try this now Thanks

Comment: Works awesome, THANKS. But how can i modify those values in modal? it's too much difficult?

Comment: i've navigated into DOM and found the values by console, but i don't know how to modify them into modal.

Comment: Yes you will be going to need extra efforts.Go step by step First go through all JavaScript basic event if you know that you can do anything with framework.

Comment: Ok, ill appreciate it if you could help me with that. But if its too hard i'll try to learn a little bit more about modal then proceed to do that part of the exercise. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Better way i suggest use jquery data table plugin.https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Comment: @xblade52 please study plugin this  to show data in tabular form

Comment: so many documets are available for this plugin.If got any problem i will help you out thanks EnjoyYYYYY.

Comment: Man, please help me. I couldn't do anything. If you got time please update the code and try to make modal update table's data. I just want to see how it is done, because i got nothing with trying. I learn another things but didn't make the goal.

Answer (score 0):

To show a modal you need to add `data-toogle='modal' data-target="#myModal"` to the button.

`#myModal`is the modal ID

```
<td><button type="button" data-id="1" class="btn btn-default editButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button></td>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <!-- your modal content -->
</div>
```

Also don't forget to include the library itself after the jQuery you inserted

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

See more examples here on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)